# Create anonymous function using generic type parameters?

Tags: .net, generics, anonymous-methods

Let's say I have this method:

```
int MyMethod(int arg)
{
    return arg;
}
```

I can create an anonymous equivalent of that like this:

```
Func<int, int> MyAnonMethod = (arg) =>
{
    return arg;
};
```

But let's say I have a method that uses generic type parameters like this:

```
T MyMethod<T>(T arg)
{
    return arg;
}
```

How can I create *that* as an anonymous method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. You create a concrete delegate object, one that specifies the type of `T`
2. You *declare* the delegate in a generic context, using an existing `T`.

### Example of the first

```
var f = new Func<int, int>(MyMethod<int>);
var result = f(10);
```

### Example of the second

```
T Test<T>()
{
    T arg = default(T);
    Func<T, T> func = MyMethod; // Generic delegate
    return func(arg);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
T MyMethod<T>(T arg)
{
    return arg;
}
```

You will not be able to persuade the compiler or intellisense to carry the generic `T` with the delegate in a non-generic context and then work out the actual `T` when calling it.

So this is not legal:

```
void Test()
{
    var fn = new Func<T, T>(MyMethod<T>);
    fn(10); // returns 10
    fn("Test"); // returns "Test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All concrete methods from generics are anonymous. You can't have it the other way around.

It's simple to do that:

```
T MyMethod<T>(T arg)
{
    return arg;
}

//...

Func<int, int> MyAnonMethod = MyMethod<int>;
MyAnonMethod(1); // returns 1
```

If `MyMethod` is used directly, it will implicitly use a proper type, for example:

```
MyMethod(1); // returns 1 of type int
```

Comment: But this implies that I know `T` which I don't.  Just like I don't know `T` in my concrete method, I can't know `T` in my anonymous method.

Comment: You mean that in `(arg) ...`  you didn't specify `int`? is *that* what you're looking for?

Comment: Correct.  I need to be able to pass in any type.  When I call the anonymous method, I want the intellisense tooltip to show `T MyClass.MyMethod<T>(T arg)`.  Once I complete the expression as `int i = MyMethod(1)`, I then want intellisense tooltip to show `int MyClass.MyMethod<int>(int arg)`.

Comment: Not sure about IntelliSense, but `MyMethod(1)` will both accept and return an `int` (Notice, `MyMethod`, not `MyAnonMethod`. `int` is implicit).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Func<T, T> MyAnonMethod = (arg) =>
{
    return arg;
};
```

if you're at a spot (method, class) where you have a `T`. If you don't have a `T` you could create a method that returns a Func like:

```
Func<T, T> CreateMyAnonMethod()
{
    returns (arg) => { return arg; };
}
```